# Selenium Do at the same time things in multiple tabs

Tags: selenium

I want to open with selenium 5 tabs where it goes to a site and it search something at multiple tabs. But if in one tab the search hasn't happened then the other tab doesn't open until the search to become.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
for i in range(5):
    driver.execute_script(f"window.open('about:blank', 'secondtab{i}');")
    driver.switch_to.window(f'secondtab{i}')
    driver.get('https://www.techwithtim.net/')
    new = driver.find_element_by_name('s')
    new.send_keys('tgfvgb')
    new.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

I want to open all the tabs together and do every thing at the same time.

Comment: Look into multi processing with threads in order to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can not open the 5 WebDriver at the same time because the for loop execute till condition complete. Other then this, you can either do the cross browser testing.